# Is using the WebBrowser object for an API bad?

Tags: .net, api, webbrowser-control

I plan on making an API for a cool website I found in VB.net.  The easiest method at my disposal is to create a WebBrowser object, hide it, and then force it to do all the dirty work.

Now, is this a bad idea?  Is this too hacked up to be useful?

Thanks for your opinions!

Comment: Ask the web site's operator. If you cannot get a web API like REST or SOAP, ask for the web site update schedule and test your code against the new version before it goes live. Otherwise you will always have compatibility issues, webclient or webbrowser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WebClient instead. It has no interface to be hidden.

Comment: What if the page dynamically updates and I need to get that data, will it still work?

Comment: That makes me start to wonder what you are doing, if you need to interact with things that usually need human intervention. Maybe we need to know more about the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Take a look at Cleverbot.com.  That is what I want my API to work with.  That is as legit as it gets :)  Sorry for sounding scummy.

Comment: I should have been more clear; I didn't necessarily mean that what you were doing was suspicious, just that it invited asking what you were trying to do because it seemed like there might be an easier way.